# Complex series and sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

**Question:** Let $\ell_2(\mathbb{C})$ be the set of all complex sequences $(z_n)\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |z_n|^2$ is convergent, i.e.,
$$\ell_2(\mathbb{C}) = \left\{ (z_n)_n\;:\; \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |z_n|^2 \;\;\text{is convergent}\right\}.$$
If $(z_n),(w_n)\in\ell_2(\mathbb{C})$, show that $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z_n\overline{w}_n}$ is convergent.

**My attempt:** Let $(z_n),(w_n)\in\ell_2(\mathbb{C})$. It follows from the Schwarz inequality that
$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z_n\overline{w}_n\right|^2 \leq \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |z_n|^2\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |w_n|^2\right).$$
Since $(z_n),(w_n)\in\ell_2(\mathbb{C})$, then the both series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |z_n|^2}$ and  $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |w_n|^2}$ converge and, therefore, the product $\displaystyle{\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |z_n|^2\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |w_n|^2\right)}$ converges. Since such a product converges and the above inequality holds, then we can conclude from the comparison test that $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z_n\overline{w}_n}$ is convergent.

Comment: It follows from the Schwarz inequality that
$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z_n\overline{w}_n\right|^2 \leq \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |z_n|^2\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |w_n|^2\right).$$ That's not quite right. You start by taking the absolute value of something you don't know exists yet?

Comment: I think you are right. The Schwarz inequality holds for finite complex sequences. In the case of infinite sequences (and sums), it is not guaranteed, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is okay, assuming that you can use the intended version of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Alternatively, you can work with the partial sums and then take the limit.

The infinite sum in the conclusion defines an inner product of the two elements in $\ell_2$.